# How to compare a String-Array

Tags: android, imageview, arrays, navigation-drawer

Android devs!

1) I have tried to compare a string-array declared in my **string.xml** (I don't know if it's possible):

```
<string-array name="menu_array">
        <item>Pizzas</item>
        <item>Baguetes</item>
        <item>Calzones</item>
        <item>Esfihas</item>
        <item>Refrigerantes</item>
        <item>Vinhos</item>
        <item>Cervejas</item>        
</string-array>
```

2) I have a layout with an ImageView, to update images corresponding to each menu item string-array:

```
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="selecionarOpcao"
    android:padding="32dp" />
```

3)I am using a navigation drawer. This is a class with a Fragment to show an image of item called:

```
public static class MenuFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PRODUTOS_NUMBER = "produtos_number";

    public MenuFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View rootView =
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu, container, false);

        int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PRODUTOS_NUMBER);
        String menu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array)[i];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(
            menu.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()), "drawable",
            getActivity().getPackageName());

        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image))
            .setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(menu);
        return rootView;
     }
 }
```

4) I would like to call different Intents according to the item clicked, the image loaded... I have trying this form, but not succesfully.

```
public void selecionarOpcao(View view)
{
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.image:
        String[] produto =
            getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array);
        if (produto.toString().equals("pizza")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, ListarActivity.class));
        } //Others Condictions
        break;
    }
}
```

As I compare these strings? Thanks guys!

Comment: you have to do a foreach on produto foreach(string s in produto) { if(s.equals("pizza")){ // do your stuff} }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String[] produto = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array);
if (produto.toString().equals("pizza")) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, ListarActivity.class));
}//Others Condictions
```

replace with

```
String[] produto = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.menu_array);
for(String item in produto) {
    if (item.equals("pizza")) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, ListarActivity.class));
    }//Others Condictions
}
```

**UPDATE:**
You can try set tag with string

```
((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setTag(menu); // in onCreateView
```

And use this tag in listener:

```
public void selecionarOpcao(View view)
{
    String menuString = (String) view.getTag();
    if(menuString.equals("Pizzas")){ 
    // start activity
    } else if /// Other Condition
}
```