# Match Image Array item with button Android Studio

Tags: android, arrays, android-studio

I'm new to android studio and i need help.

So far what i have created:

1) Array name "Item" that contains 6 image **"1,2,3,4,5,6".**

2) Button A with 3 same image from Array **"Item" = "1,2,3".**

3) Button B with 3 same image from Array **"Item" = "4,5,6".**

My question:
how to write ***if (item in Button A) matched (Array "Item")?*** 
Thanks

Comment: Check logic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710947/android-compare-arrays & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476821/how-to-compare-a-string-array

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried any code yet? If so, can you add it to the question, so we can see what you have tried so far.